# How To Add The Data From an Alert View To my Table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I Have Created a Table With some list of options and one of it is "ADD NEW ROW".If the user clicks on it he will get an alert view.i have customized that alert view with a text field.But the problem is i am not able to add that data entered in the text field to my table view.

Some one pls help.

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView commitEditingStyle: (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
{
    [self.listOfCategories removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.tableViewC reloadData];
} 
else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert)
{
    UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your title here!" message:@"...." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0,    260.0, 25.0)];
    [myTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [myAlertView addSubview:myTextField];
    [myAlertView show];
    [myAlertView release];
    [self.listOfCategories insertObject:@"Add" atIndex:[self.listOfCategories count]];
    [self.tableViewC reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Maybe show some code, what you have so far, what you have tried to put the text in the table etc.

Comment: You have to use the UIAlertViewDelegate methods. Check the docs for that.

Comment: Here is where i got stuck....and i dont know what to do next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in you alertView Delegate write this code..

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {
      if(buttonIndex==0)
        {
               NSIndexPath *newPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:yourArray.count inSection:0];
               [yourArray insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",yourTextField.text] atIndex:newPath.row];
               [tableView reloadData];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of it as adding a row to your table view. Think of it as adding an entry to your datasource. How are you storing your data? If it is an array, add the object to the array then reload your table.